# Comparing strings in PHP

Tags: php

String comparison in PHP seems little difficult. I don't know if any other ways to do it.

For example say:

```
$t1 = "CEO";
$t2 = "Chairman";
$t3 = "Founder";

$title = "CEO, Chairman of the Board";

if (!strcmp($t1, $title)) {
    echo $title."<br>"; echo $Fname."<br>"; echo $Lname."<br>";
} else if (!strcmp($t2, $title)) {
    echo $title."<br>"; echo $Fname."<br>"; echo $Lname."<br>";
} else if (!strcmp($t3, $title)) {
    echo $title."<br>"; echo $Fname."<br>"; echo $Lname."<br>";
}
```

This isn't giving any result as above `$title` has word `$t1` and `$t2` in it. How can I do this?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Every one is confused?? I dont know why ok let me explain. $t1,$t2,$t3 are constant. value of $titile keep changing say it can be some times "CEO","Founder,"Chairman" or some times it can be "editor","developer" etc. so what I want is if $title includes contants $t1,$t2 and $t3 then it should give first name and last name. variables $Fname and $Lname details are not included in this code.

Comment: everyone was confused because it's not clear from your code what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) tests on **exact equality**. You rather want to test if the string contains the given *part*. In that case rather use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) or [`stristr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php). Both can be used the following way:

```
if (stripos($title, $t1) === false) {
    // $title does not contain $t1
}
if (stristr($title, $t1) === false) {
    // $title does not contain $t1
}
```

When you want *case sensitive* comparison (e.g. `chairman` should not be equal to `Chairman`), then use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) or [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to print that string if either of `$t1`, `$t2`, `$t3` occurs in `$title`:

```
foreach (array($t1, $t2, $t3) as $titlePart) {
    if (strpos($title, $titlePart) !== false) {
        echo $title . "<br>" . $Fname . "<br>" . $Lname . "<br>";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting title on "," and using in_array... or strcmp on the individual parts of the array...   or finding a whole new and better solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you want?

```
$t1 = "CEO";
$t2 = "Chairman";
$t3 = "Founder";

$title = "CEO, Chairman of the Board";

if (!is_integer(strpos($t1, $title))) {
    echo $title."<br>"; echo $Fname."<br>"; echo $Lname."<br>";
} else if (!sis_integer(strpos($t2, $title))) {
    echo $title."<br>"; echo $Fname."<br>"; echo $Lname."<br>";
} else if (!is_integer(strpos($t3, $title))) {
    echo $title."<br>"; echo $Fname."<br>"; echo $Lname."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are attempting to do.

If you are simply checking for existance or position use strpos()

```
$t1 = "CEO";

$title = "CEO, Chairman of the Board";

$startposition = strpos($title, $t1);

if ($startposition === false) {
     //not found
} else {
   //found (@ index $startposition)
}
```

Again, not 100% sure what you are trying to find/do from this data, but hopefully that'll get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (stripos($title, $t1) !=  false && stripos($title, $t2) !=  false && stripos($title, $t3) !=  false ) {
    echo $Fname ."<br />" . $Lname ; 
}
```

based on your comment - this is what you want. If t1, t2 and t3 ALL occur then print out  first name and last name.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use preg_match() or strcasecmp() when searching strings like this, because those can ignore case.  strcomp() is case sensitive and wont catch "CEO, chairman of the Board", for example.